# Can't get my wireless to work on Toshiba-Satellite-C70D-B

Tags: wireless, toshiba, pastebin

I've read some of the previous questions and answers and have not yet found what I need.

I have a lot of info, but don't know what to do with it.

One thing that confuses me is I cannot "see" what networks are available, like with Windows.

[Output from Wireless Info script](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23466736/)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: @ElderGeek 
It says "too long by 11340 characters". Should I post a new question? or can I edit this question?

########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Nov 2016 09:29 EST -0500

Booted last: 11 Nov 2016 00:00 EST -0500

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release: 16.04
Codename: xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Please [edit] a link to a [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) into your question. I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Comment: @ElderGeek - Okay, I did that. I pasted the link both with and without the <> symbols because I was not sure which was correct, or which would work. Apparently they are not necessary. This is fun. What's next?

Comment: Thank you for helping us help you! I edited the formatting a bit to remove the duplicate link and make the post look a bit better.

Comment: I removed all the unneeded info from the question to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and Wi-Fi will work.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/762255/167850) for explanation.

Comment: Cool. How do I do that? @Pilot6

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/762255/167850

Comment: @Pilot6 I'd suggest you add a little explanation as to the *why*.

Comment: The previous comment explains it. I can add it to the answer.

Comment: This worked! At first I was able to "see" all the nearby networks, but attempts to connect to our home network failed. I tried several things, including deleting the connection, starting over and renaming it, and it finally worked on about the 5th try. If I have any further problems I'll make an additional comment. Otherwise, is there a problem solved button? Thank you ElderGeek @Pilot6 guntbert. You guys are awesome. I can't wait for my next "problem."